# Is it possible to display my Mac on my iPhone using a USB cable?

Tags: iphone, mac, usb, display

I've tried AirDisplay and Splashtop but they aren't fast enough, they are always delayed . I need something to see videos and play games without any kind of delay. Because AirDisplay and Splashtop use wifi connection they doesn't work the way I want. Is there any option to mirror my Mac to an iPhone but using a USB cable so it can't be delayed?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

They are the only options as of now. They are slow because of your internet.

Even USB have speed limitation.

And using a USB cable 6 or 12 feet long would defeat the purpose (you are to close to the Mac for any benefit).

Your WiFi speed should be good enough to watch streaming Videos without delay showing > 200kb/s.

To check, click on the WiFi while holding the alt key, that will open more detailed information on your WiFi.

In there it should say

MCS index >10

Answer (score 0):

I use an app called Presence from Flying Mac. Here's the [link](http://flyingmac.com/presence/). Just watch the slideshow on their homepage, to get an overview of the app's capabilities. The developers are very helpful as well.